# Is it possible to read all push notifications in didReceiveRemoteNotification function?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
      print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}
```

So in this AppDelegate's function I am able to read all of the push notifications coming from our app/server. 
I would like to know if I can get all the different types of notifications and read their title and body, for example notifications that come from iMessage (SMS), Instagram, Messenger and other push notifications coming to my phone?

Is it possible to somehow access the whole notifications-centre and read all of the incoming push notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not possible.
Your app receives notifications based on its bundle ID.
So Instagram's bundle ID won't match yours.